# Perform assembly signature verification in .Net 6

Tags: .net-6.0, digital-signature, strongname

strong-name signatures are not validated when an assembly is loaded into a full-trust domain (Mycomputer)

In the [following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature#disable-the-strong-name-bypass-feature-for-a-single-application) it is explained how to disable bypass of the signature verification for .Net Framework

Would someone know hot to deactivate bypassTrustedAppStrongNames in .Net Core ?

Thanks in advance

PS : We can see with the following code that on Linux or Windows the applications runs in FullTrust

```
Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().IsFullyTrusted
```

I have tryed the [following configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/disable-strong-name-bypass-feature#disable-the-strong-name-bypass-feature-for-all-applications) to disable the bypass running a .Net 6 app on windows (signed exe that loads an unsigned dll):

```
Create a DWORD entry with a value of 0 named AllowStrongNameBypass under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework keys
```

I expected that my application in .Net 6 would not load an unsigned assembly loaded from an signed executable assembly

Actual result is that the unsigned assembly is loaded for my .Net core App

Answer (score 0):

[modern .NET does not validate strong name signatures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named) by design.